# Rendered LWC should not contain extra attribute in rendered element

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I defined some styles like this

```css
.tableRow {
padding: 8px;
}
```

But, when it is rendered some extra attribute is added to this class like this

```css
.tableRow[c-test_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx] {

}
```

**Can we prevent the addition of this extra attribute? Due to this, my styles are not getting applied to that component**

Answer (score 5):

It's working exactly as intended. Because not all supported browsers support proper CSS in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), these "extra attributes" are added such that the `tableRow` class in `c-test` won't conflict with, override, or bleed into `tableRow` in `c-test2` (or any other component). The runtime is responsible for transforming your CSS into the correct CSS for the component. Note that this question is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info), so all I can really say here is that the CSS is working as intended. Either (a) you're trying to override or apply a style from a parent component that belongs to a child component, which is not allowed by the rules of Aura and LWC, or (b) you've scoped your styles incorrectly and are thus not being applied. Without seeing your actual code and an "X"-focused question, it's not clear what solution we should suggest for you (or, possibly, another option not listed here entirely).